# How can I autogenerate an interface in an Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interface

I am trying to find a way how to autogenerate interface in component. Here is an example:

Interface:

```
export default interface Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
export default class Person {
  @Input() id: number; 
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

Is there something like this? (this is just pseudo code)

```
export default class Person(props:Person) {

}
```

So what I am asking is, how can I pass the properties from the interface in this class automatically, so I wont need to write the properties one by one?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it right, but your class may implement the interface. This way you would have access to the properties defined within the interface. `export default class Person implements Person`

Comment: I want to pass the properties from properties something like 
```
export default class Person (props) {}
```

and not one by one like this:
```
export default class Person {
@Input() id: number;
@Input() name: string;
}
```